# How to configure Python email script to the latest AOL connection settings?

Tags: python, email, smtp, mail-server

I virtually know nothing about Python and I'm using the following Python script to send HTML emails to my customers :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
addr_to   = 'example@domain.com'
addr_from = 'Me <me@domain.com>'
smtp_server = 'smtp.aol.com'
smtp_user   = 'username@aol.com'
smtp_pass   = 'password'
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['To'] = addr_to
msg['From'] = addr_from
msg['Subject'] = 'Email subject'
text = "Plain text goes here"
html = """\
HTML version goes here.
"""
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Recently AOL sent me a message asking me to update my email application to the latest secure connection settings which are described in this table :

[AOL settings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSwGR.png)

I wanna know how can implement the settings given in the table into my Python code ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
```

to

```
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server)
```